# Clear UITextField Placeholder text on tap

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In Xcode4 I've created some placeholder text for a UITextField and I'd like it to clear when the user taps in the box.

So, in the Attributes Inspector for the text field I've clicked "Clear when editing begins" however this does not immediately remove the text when I tap in the text box (it only disappears when you start typing).

Is there any way of removing the placeholder text immediately on tapping in the text box?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

make your ViewController the delegate of the textField and implement those two methods:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = nil;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = @"Your Placeholdertext";
}
```

Comment: In the second method you have to check that the textfield has empty value or not?

Comment: nope. The placeholder text just isn't visible if there is "regular" text.

Comment: i have add some code into my answer to check is text field is empty or not

Comment: FYI, there's a bug on iOS 7.0 when you set UITextField as center-aligned, assigned a placeholder for it, then clear the placeholder (whether nil or @""). Start editing UITextField, you'll find the cursor at weird position.

Comment: FYI, the bug is still there in iOS 8.0

Answer (score 9):

The solution provided by Matthias Bauch works well, but what happens when you have more than one `UITextField` to worry about? Now you have to identify which `UITextField` is referred to in  `textFieldDidEndEditing:textField` (possibly by use of the tag property), and that results in more unnecessary code and  logic.

A much simpler solution: simply assign a clear color to the placeholder text , and when done editing, revert back to it's original color. This way, your `textFieldDidEndEditing:textField` doesn't have to identify the `textField` to set back its corresponding text after it was nullified as in Bauch's solution.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField setValue:[UIColor placeholderColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
}
```

Comment: This could cause app store rejection for using private API

Answer (score 3):

You should also check if text filed is empty then you should put place holder again

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = nil;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
   if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0))
   {
       [textField setText:@""];
       textField.placeholder = @"Your Placeholdertext";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this..

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.placeholder=nil;
}
```

don't forget to add the delegate for the textfield to your file Owner.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one TextField

1) Add String variable to your class

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController {

var placeHolder = ""
```

2) Add UITextFieldDelegate

```
extension YourViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    placeHolder = textField.placeholder ?? ""
    textField.placeholder = ""
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.placeholder == ""{
    textField.placeholder = placeHolder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file declare a function like

`-(IBAction)clear:(id)sender;`

attach this function to your touchdown event of your `UITextField`.

in your .m file

```
 -(IBAction)clear:(id)sender 

{
   myplaceHolderText.text=@"";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.placeholder=nil;
}
```

textfield delegate make place holder value to nil

Answer (score 0):

The @etayluz 's solution is better (my opinion), because you don't need to worry about assigning placeholder'a text again.
If you have custom textFields in different places of your app and want them to behave equally (as I need in my case) you can add this code to your custom TextField's class:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
     private func setup() {
    //do additional setup like attributedPlaceholder, inset, etc.
        self.delegate = self
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

//    MARK: UITextFieldDelegate methods

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.setValue(UIColor.clearColor(), forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.setValue(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
    }
}
```

But if you need to have specific UITextFieldDelegate's methods for individual textField you DO need to implement this logic for it individually:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: CustomTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
textFields = [emailTextField, passwordTextField]
        for textField in textFields {
            textField.delegate = self
        }

//    MARK: UITextFieldDelegate methods

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.setValue(UIColor.clearColor(), forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.setValue(UIColor.lightGrayColor(), forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of **SWIFT 3 or later**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.placeholder = nil
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.placeholder = "Text Placeholder"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On Button action Event put this Code:

```
txtName.placeholder = @"";
```