# Placeholder text for a password text field is shown as a password rather than text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a text field in my view, which has secured text entry (as it is a password field) and placeholder text of "Password". However, upon running my application, the "Password" placeholder is replaced with 8 dots, as if it were a password. How do I change it such that the original text is displayed?

Comment: Can you add some code or screenshots of your storyboard?

Comment: This is worth a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421850/hide-placeholder-programatically-using-swift-3x

Comment: Check this , May be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532874/clear-uitextfield-placeholder-text-on-tap

Comment: @Gareth That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need to write any code for this. Just set the following properties of `UITextField`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I currently have set up (with the addition of the clear button being visible), but it still secures the placeholder text. Is it a problem with the simulator from previous builds?

Comment: I have used the same setup and getting no issues. I have added the screenshot of the running app.